# How to use Url.Content("~/asdf") inside automapper projection

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, automapper

I am trying to use the UrlHelper's Content method inside an automapper projection, but it fails after the first request.

My map creation code looks like the following:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext) {
  base.Initialize(requestContext);

  Mapper.CreateMap<MyObject, MyMappedObject>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Url, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => Url.Content("~/something/") + src.Id));
}
```

The first request works fine, but subsequent requests throw a NullReferenceException with the following stack trace:

```
at System.Web.HttpServerVarsCollection.Get(String name)
at System.Web.Mvc.UrlRewriterHelper.WasThisRequestRewritten(HttpContextBase httpContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.UrlRewriterHelper.WasRequestRewritten(HttpContextBase httpContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.PathHelpers.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.PathHelpers.GenerateClientUrlInternal(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.PathHelpers.GenerateClientUrl(HttpContextBase httpContext, String contentPath)
at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(String contentPath, HttpContextBase httpContext)
at System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Content(String contentPath)
```

The interesting part is if I cache the Url.Content() part before the mapping, things work fine:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext) {
  base.Initialize(requestContext);

  var url = Url.Content("~/something/");
  Mapper.CreateMap<MyObject, MyMappedObject>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Url, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => url + src.Id));
}
```

btw this code is simplified, but for my use case it is used as part of a json response, so I cannot move the Url.Content() part to a view.

Is this an automapper issue, an MVC issue, or more likely something I'm doing incorrectly?  Is there a cleaner solution other than just "caching" the url part in a variable before the mapping code?

Comment: As an aside, the reason why this fails is when the MapFrom part is evaluated.  The function is always evaluated when Mapper.Map() is called.  So in your second way of mapping, you've captured the result of Url.Content() in a closure, so that when the MapFrom function is evaluated, it's able to get at the value of "url" from the local variable.

In the first example, the Url.Content function is not evaluated until Map() is called, which is much later, I'm guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Mapper.CreateMap<TSource, TDest>()`

This should be done only once per App Domain, perfectly in the `Application_Start` method in `Global.asax`. What you do here is that you redefine your mapping rules everytime a controller is initialized which is not correct. A great place to do this is to use a [custom resolver](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers).

Comment: Thanks for the help with this.  While putting the createmap code in one central place is useful, having to use custom resolvers everywhere that I need to access unique resources may add some complexity.  I'll give it a go, though